# How to get a django instance to have one to many users relation

Tags: django

I have a company table as follows:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None)
```

My plan is that a given company instance can have more than one user account tied to it.
But from above, when a company is created, the users field is ending up with all the users in the users table.

That is not I want. I want that users are manually added rather than just populating the field with all users in the database:
[image]

How can I set this up so that a given company instance can only have the users added to it rather than all database users?

Comment: My understanding is that the object you've screenshotted has no users added to it. Rather, this is a field allowing you to add any user you want to the many-to-many relationship. If you add users to it, those users will look different.

Comment: @NickODell I think that is right. Thank you. I just did a query and it is empty for a give instance. Thank you